# Typescript - Do we have any tool/extension that I can use to identify design smells

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, design-patterns, single-page-application

I am working on Angular project. I want to find out the design smells in Typescript code. Do we have any tool/extension that I can use to find out all the design smells those are present in my project.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.sonarsource.com/ts/

Comment: Thanks @Pakira for your reply. What you suggested is for code smells and I am looking for design smells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `smellscan-ts` extension that we can use in Visual Code.

Link: https://github.com/abhipsb/smellscan-ts.

One more informative issue that I raised: https://github.com/abhipsb/smellscan-ts/issues/1